# How to avoid custom/Server error in web site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, url-rewriting

I have asp.net web application located on server I want to avoid all custom and server error from my site.

For that I have used

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPage/TryAgainLater.aspx">   <error redirect="~/ErrorPage/PageNotFound.aspx" statusCode="404"/> </customErrors>
```

Using above code will able avoid some issue. ie.

Suppose "http://Exaple.com/Careers.aspx" Page available in my site then

Case 1. http://Exaple.com/Careersss.aspx "It was working correct as per above rule".

Case 2. http://Exaple.com/!@##Careersss.aspx "Not working"
Note : Here I add special character

Case 3: http://Exaple.com/Careersss.aspxxxx "Not working"
Note : add character after ".aspx"

case 4: http://Exaple.com/Careersss.aspx/!@!@!@! "Not works design breaking here".
Note : Add '/' with special character.

please help me when user get case 2,3,4 then they automatically redirected to error page.

Thanks In advance.

Comment: So... what's the question? And how is it related to javascript?

Comment: @kirilloid I imagine it has to do with his second case where he's using the hash symbol, but it's not at all clear from the question.

Comment: Here I want to avoid unnecessary URL if some one from out side  try to distract our site then I just want they directly goes in to error page.

Comment: Hi Yashwant Kumar Sahu, I assume that cases 2, 3, and 4 are cases of wrong syntax of the URL. It's like requesting a URL ending with .ne or .co while it should be .net or .com, respectively.

Comment: Yes case 2,3,4 are wrong URL, My problem is "when user explicitly hit wring URL in site it will redirect to my error page. i.e "http://www.snapdeal.com/@@@@@@@@@@###local-deals-pune-Health_Beauty?category=1,6,7"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For above problem we have to change IIS Setting  please refer :

http://www.braintrove.com/id/46/page/2#Configure-IIS-for-custom-error-pages

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webtopics/archive/2008/05/28/iis-7-0-http-error-pages.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change IIS settings, you can install your own handler for 404 errors in Global.asax. Just add this method to our Global.asax.cs code-behind file:

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
    if (response.StatusCode == 404 && response.SubStatusCode == 0)
    {
        response.Redirect("/test/TryAgainLater.aspx?error=NotFound");
        response.End();
    }
}
```

If it does not fix the issue and you are still getting 404 error page, add this setting to your web.config file:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```